# Код работает только в режиме отладки

Tags: javascript, ajax

Имеется код, который отсылает данные.

```
 function savePost() {
    var title = $("#productName").val();
    var description = $("#productDescription").val();
    var price = $("#productPrice").val();
    var urlImage = $("#productUrl").val();
    var imageContent = null;

    if (file != null) {
        var fReader = new FileReader();
        fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        imageContent = fReader.result;

    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/productgallery/",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            title: title,
            description: description,
            price: price,
            image: imageContent
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {

            if (file != null)
                upload(file);

            loadGallery("tblProductGallery", function () {
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Но он работает только в режиме отладки, если же я выполняю его без режима отладки - то теряется содержимое imageContent и на сервер приходит null.

В связи с чем вопрос - с чем это можеть быть связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#submitButton").click(function () {

var imageContent = null;

if (file != null) {
    var fReader = new FileReader();

    fReader.onloadend = function () {
        imageContent = fReader.result;
        savePost(imageContent);
    };

    fReader.readAsDataURL(file);      
}        
});

function savePost(imageContent) {
    var title = $("#productName").val();
    var description = $("#productDescription").val();
    var price = $("#productPrice").val();
    var urlImage = $("#productUrl").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/productgallery/",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        title: title,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        image: imageContent
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {

        if (file != null)
            upload(file);

        loadGallery("tblProductGallery", function () {
        });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Не надо копипастить чужие ответы.